# problem assigning declarative values in asp:hyperlink. error: this is not scriptlet. will output as plain text

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, declarative

I am trying to do this:

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl='<%= WebContext.RootUrl %><%= WebContext.CurrentUser.UserName %>' runat="server" Text='<%= GetProfileImage(WebContext.CurrentUser.AccountId) %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

But am getting the error:

> this is not scriptlet. will output as
>   plain text.

when I mouse over my declarative statements.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use data binding syntax `<%# %>`. Just be sure that your hyperlink is either in a databound control, such as a ListView item template, or that you explicitly call `DataBind()` on the control from code-behind.

Comment: just so i am clear, the "#" means databound and the "=" means server-side value but not necessarily databound?

Comment: That's about right. '<%= %>' denotes a string literal, and is unrelated to databinding.

Answer (score 23):

You cannot use `<%= ... %>` literals to set properties of server-side controls.

Instead, you can use a normal (client-side) `<a>` tag, like this:

```
<a href="<%= WebContext.RootUrl %><%= WebContext.CurrentUser.UserName %>"><%= GetProfileImage(WebContext.CurrentUser.AccountId) %></a>
```

If `GetProfileImage` doesn't return HTML tags, make sure to escape it.

Answer (score 9):

You can still populate an <asp:HyperLink> if you provide the **ID** and **runat="server"** properties.  You can then set any property of the HyperLink from code-behind.

ASP Code:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="myLink" runat="server"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
public void Page_Init()
{
    myLink.NavigateURL = WebContext.RootUrl + WebContext.CurrentUser.UserName;
    myLink.Text = GetProfileImage(WebContext.CurrentUser.AccountId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href='<%= WebContext.RootUrl %><%= WebContext.CurrentUser.UserName %>'><%= GetProfileImage(WebContext.CurrentUser.AccountId) %></a>
```